# Use one windows form to increment progress bar of another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I was just wondering if I have a form Form1, and declare

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   GraphLoadProgress loadProgress;

   public Form1()
   {
      loadProgress = new GraphLoadProgress();
      loadProgress.Show();
      // do some stuff
      loadProgress.progress = 25; // increment by 25%
      // more stuff 
      for (int i = 0; i < 65; i++) // increment by 65%
      {
         loadProgress.progress = 1;
      }
      // even more stuff
      loadProgress.progress = 10; // increment by 10%

      // blah blah
      loadProgress.progress = 100; // make sure it goes over 100%
   }
}
```

and in my GraphLoadProgress form is the following

```
public partial class GraphLoadProgress : Form
{
    public int progress { get; set; }

    private void StartBackgroundWork()
    {
        if (Application.RenderWithVisualStyles)
            progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        else
        {
            progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            progressBar.Maximum = 100;
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        //backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBar.Value > progressBar.Maximum)
            this.Close();
        progressBar.Increment(progress);
    }
}
```

This obviously does not work because the timer will update and increment even when i did not want it to, is there any way to increment the progress bar, and only increment with by a certain amount while the progress bar is still updating?

Comment: Friendly pro advise to anonymous downvoters: never downvote without leaving a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the setter of the progress property directly, something like:

```
private int _progress = 0;
public int progress {
    get { return _progress; }
    set {
        _progress = value;
        if (progressBar.InvokeRequired) {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {progressBar.Value == value;});
        } else {
            progressBar.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

That way you can set from outside what the value of the progressbar should be. The `InvokeRequired` check makes it possible to set the value from a different thread.

More closely mimicing the behaviour you have would be a WriteOnly property (only a setter):

```
public int progress {
    set {
        if (progressBar.InvokeRequired) {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {progressBar.Increment(value);});
        } else {
            progressBar.Increment(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can always just add a public `Increment` method to the form.

```
public void IncrementProgress(int Value)
{
    if (progressBar.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {progressBar.Increment(Value);});
    } else {
        progressBar.Increment(Value);
    }
}
```

You should add checks for the Maximum value in any case, to avoid exceptions.

Comment: by any chance would you know how to close the loading window once it hits 100%?

Comment: @user3078930 Since you control all pathways that alter the progressbar (set it to be private as well in the designer) you can just add a check in the setter for example. Alter the value and if its >= 100 call `this.close()`.